# Create list of nodes by copying from another lists

Tags: xslt, copy

I have a XSLT template where I need to merge two lists of nodes conditionally. I have the following two XML fragments:

```
<vo>
    <field name="userLoginName"       nameLDAP="uid"              type="String"/>
    <field name="displayName"         nameLDAP="displayName"      type="String"/>
    <field name="firstName"           nameLDAP="givenName"        type="String"/>
    <field name="lastName"            nameLDAP="sn"               type="String"/>
    <field name="mail"                nameLDAP="mail"             type="String"/>
    <field name="userPassword"        nameLDAP="userPassword"     type="String" hidden="true"/>
    <field name="center"              nameLDAP="center"           type="String"/>
</vo>

<input>
    <field name="userPassword"/>
    <field name="oldPasswordInQuotes" nameLDAP="unicodePwd"       type="byte[]"/>        
</input>
```

I want to  create a xml fragment  that will have the same nodeas as input/field. For each one of those nodes I want to check if there is a node with the same name in the list vo/field. If there is, then it should be copied to the new list. Otherwise, it should copy the same node we are iterating over. In this case the output should be something like this:

```
<field name="userPassword"        nameLDAP="userPassword"     type="String" hidden="true"/>
<field name="oldPasswordInQuotes" nameLDAP="unicodePwd"       type="String"/>
```

So far I've the following transformation:

```
    <xsl:variable name="fields" select="vo/field" />

    <xsl:variable name='allParameters'>
        <xsl:for-each select="input/field">
            <xsl:variable name="inputFieldName" select="@name"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$fields[@name = $inputFieldName]">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$fields[@name = $inputFieldName]"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:message>Parameters <xsl:copy-of select="$allParameters" /> </xsl:message>

    <xsl:for-each select="$allParameters">
        <xsl:message>Parameter <xsl:value-of select="@name" /> found !!! </xsl:message>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

The output is

```
Parameters <field name="userPassword" nameLDAP="userPassword" type="String" hidden="true"/><field name="oldPasswordInQuotes" nameLDAP="unicodePwd" type="byte[]"/>
Parameter  found !!!
```

The first xsl:message seems to show that the copy worked fine, but when I try to iterate over it, it is obviously not working(there is only one message "Parameter found" and it is not showing the parameter name). What am I missing?

Comment: Why does your requested output show `<field name="oldPasswordInQuotes" nameLDAP="unicodePwd"       type="String"/>`? Where did the `"String"` value come from? -- P.S. You should post a complete, reproducible example; working with snippets out of their context is very difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you want something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="vo" match="vo/field" use="@name" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="root/input/field">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="key('vo', @name)">
                <xsl:copy-of select="key('vo', @name)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to a **wel-formed input**:

```
<root>
    <vo>
        <field name="userLoginName"       nameLDAP="uid"              type="String"/>
        <field name="displayName"         nameLDAP="displayName"      type="String"/>
        <field name="firstName"           nameLDAP="givenName"        type="String"/>
        <field name="lastName"            nameLDAP="sn"               type="String"/>
        <field name="mail"                nameLDAP="mail"             type="String"/>
        <field name="userPassword"        nameLDAP="userPassword"     type="String" hidden="true"/>
        <field name="center"              nameLDAP="center"           type="String"/>
    </vo>
    <input>
        <field name="userPassword"/>
        <field name="oldPasswordInQuotes" nameLDAP="unicodePwd"       type="byte[]"/>        
    </input>
</root>
```

results in:

```
<field name="userPassword" nameLDAP="userPassword" type="String" hidden="true"/>
<field name="oldPasswordInQuotes" nameLDAP="unicodePwd" type="byte[]"/>
```

---

### Edit:

To answer your question regarding the number of messages in your test: there is only one `$allParameters` node; to iterate over its inner nodes (assuming XSLT 2.0), try:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$allParameters/field">
    <!-- your code here -->
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: thanks. You are right, the question was not that well formulated. but your suggestion worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: I just posted a slightly different question, in order to merge attributes from elements in both list. Maybe you have a good tip on how to do it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26850542/combine-node-atttributes-from-two-lists